# Unity UI Test Automation displays error, after compiling

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have installed from Asset store "Unity UI Test Automation". when i run it, console displays error:

> Exception: Operation timed out: UITest+ObjectAppeared`1[FirstScreen]
>   '' at System.Environment.get_StackTrace() in
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System/Environment.cs:line
>   227 at UITest.WaitFor(.Condition condition) in
>   /Users/bbaitikova/MeTestProject/Assets/UITest/UITest.cs:line 70 at
>   UITestExample+c_Iterator1.MoveNext() in
>   /Users/bbaitikova/MeTestProject/Assets/UITest/Examples/UITestExample.cs:line
>   28 at UITest+cIterator1.MoveNext() in
>   /Users/bbaitikova/MeTestProject/Assets/UITest/UITest.cs:line 51 at
>   UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMoveNext(IEnumerator enumerator,
>   IntPtr returnValueAddress) in
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/Coroutines.cs:line
>   17 at
>   UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine_Auto_Internal(IEnumerator )
>   at UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine(IEnumerator routine) in
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/runtime/MonoBehaviourBindings.gen.cs:line
>   62 at UITest+cIterator0.MoveNext() in
>   /Users/bbaitikova/MeTestProject/Assets/UITest/UITest.cs:line 40 at
>   UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMoveNext(IEnumerator enumerator,
>   IntPtr returnValueAddress) in
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/Coroutines.cs:line
>   17 UITest+c_Iterator5.MoveNext () (at Assets/UITest/UITest.cs:136)
>   UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMoveNext (IEnumerator enumerator,
>   IntPtr returnValueAddress) (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/Coroutines.cs:17)

I did not touch the script, just installed from store. Does anybody have this issue? How to resolve this issue? Any thoughts would be very helpful, thanks.

Comment: Can you post a link to that asset on the asset store ? is it compatible with the Unity version you're using ?

Comment: Link: https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/72693 .  My unity version is 5.6.1p2 (asset Requires Unity 5.3.5 or higher.)